# Не записывать строку в listBox по условию ячейки

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица Excel и форма написанная в VBA. На форме очень много элементов, но интересует только один это мой любимый в кавычках ListBox. Он как бы отображает список  и всё у него хорошо, но мне понадобилось добавить ещё одно условие. В частности, допустим есть три колонки и много строчек которые и отображаются в ListBox, а как сделать так, чтобы если в 4 строке таблицы Excel допустим стоит цифра 1 (причём она может быть в нескольких строках, а может и не быть) то данная строка в ListBox бы не отображалась? 
Вот собственно и сам код:

```
Sub List_Upd()

Dim SheetDx1 As Variant
Dim SheetDx2 As Variant
Dim i As Long

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(25, 2) = 1 Then
SheetDx1 = 4
SheetDx2 = 5
Else
SheetDx1 = 7
SheetDx2 = 8
End If

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetDx1).Cells(1, 6) = 2 Then
ListBox1.Clear
Exit Sub
Else
With ListBox1
.List = Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetDx2).Cells(2, 5), _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetDx2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetDx2). _
Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row, 7)).Value
For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If IsEmpty(.List(i)) Then .RemoveItem i
        Next
    End With
End If

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, все это происходит при открытии формы, поэтому не удалять из списка, а заполнять его только нужными данными:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim aData()
Dim SheetDx1 As Byte, SheetDx2 As Byte
Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Sheets(3).Cells(25, 2) = 1 Then
            SheetDx1 = 4: SheetDx2 = 5
        Else
            SheetDx1 = 7: SheetDx2 = 8
        End If

        If .Sheets(SheetDx1).Cells(1, 6) = 2 Then Exit Sub

        With .Sheets(SheetDx2)
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
            aData = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(i, 7)).Value
        End With

        Call ChangeList(aData)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeList(aData())
Dim i As Long
    With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aData(i, 1) <> 1 And aData(i, 2) <> 1 And aData(i, 3) <> 1 Then
                .AddItem aData(i, 1)
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = aData(i, 2)
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = aData(i, 3)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное vikttur!!!! Всё поучилось, правда с ошибкой 424 но я исправил))) Просто не учёл что код у меня не в форме а в отдельном модуле, но Вы правы он вызывается именно при активации формы)))) А цифра 1 (один) у меня в таблице Excel в 9 столбце)))) в общем получилось у меня вот так и всё работает супер))))) Код написал в ответе на своё же сообщение, так как в комментарии не умещается.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо огромное vikttur!!!! Всё поучилось, правда с  ошибкой 424 но я исправил))) Просто не учёл что код у меня не в форме а в отдельном модуле, но Вы правы он вызывается именно при активации формы)))) А цифра 1 (один) у меня в таблице Excel в 9 столбце)))) в общем получилось у меня вот так и всё работает супер)))))

```
Sub List_Upd()
Dim aData()
Dim SheetDx1 As Byte, SheetDx2 As Byte
Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Sheets(3).Cells(25, 2) = 1 Then
            SheetDx1 = 4: SheetDx2 = 5
        Else
            SheetDx1 = 7: SheetDx2 = 8
        End If

        If .Sheets(SheetDx1).Cells(1, 6) = 2 Then Exit Sub

        With .Sheets(SheetDx2)
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
            aData = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(i, 9)).Value
        End With

        Call ChangeList(aData)
    End With
End Sub

Sub ChangeList(aData())
Dim i As Long
    With Форма.ListBox1
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aData(i, 5) <> 1 Then
                .AddItem aData(i, 1)
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = aData(i, 2)
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = aData(i, 3)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Работу с элементами формы правильнее проводить в модуле формы

Comment: Это то да)))) Но если все функции переместить на форму это всё не влезет))))

Comment: Если "не влезет" - нужно срочно пересматривать код и подход к реализации. В данном случае проверку поместить в процедуру вызова формы, а вот второму макросу самое место в модуле формы. При этом массив передавать в публичной переменной или (что лучше) заполнять перед заполнением списка